# Change flutter project to offline

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have been created a flutter project without enabling offline mode and now I want to enable it, so
is it possible to change current flutter project to offline mode in the android studio
and how to do it?

Comment: hey @mohammed could you please explain me what is difference b/w offline and online flutter project?

Comment: @amit.flutter I think that a online project gets the pub packages every time it runs while an offline project uses the ones stored locally. In case you work in a place without internet connection then you could NOT execute a regular project. You need that project to be offline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for later response. First open your terminal. And you can enable flutter offline mode for existing project by running following command in your project directory:

```
flutter create . --offline
```

Or disabe:

```
flutter create . --no-offline
```

Comment: Not late at all

Comment: after 3 months finally a good answer

Answer (score -1):

If your question refers to Android Studio - a project communicates with the Internet when you getting or upgrading dependencies for project. You can try to enable Gradle (Androud build system by default) Offline Mode. For more information you need to describe situation when you need to use Offile Mode.

If your question refers to a project (an app) - you can create local storage (for example with [sqf](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)) and check Internet connection with [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin for manipulate app's state when user is not online. Also, you can check `AndroidManifest.xml` file for check dependencies that are enabled in your project on Android and [this](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Internet-Permissions) guide for check iOS permission for access to the Network.