# Create or Run Flutter Project Offline or without internet

Tags: flutter

Is it possible for me to create new Flutter project offline?
Is it also possible to Run my already created application offline?
I didn't add any new package(s) to my pubspec.yaml, just plain project I created before.

I tried to create new Flutter project without internet using Terminal and Flutter New Project from VSCode, but it stuck at creating new project and retrying multiple times.
The same goes for my already created projects.

Is it possible to bypass that?

Comment: The gradle file of android app require online stuff. thats why its stuck

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055378/change-flutter-project-to-offline?rq=3

Answer (score 1):

enable this VS code setting  shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDHeS.png), here's a video to follow steps: [link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uhe1PnWWhto).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Add `"dart.offline": true` to settings.json

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055378/change-flutter-project-to-offline?rq=3

Answer (score 0):

creating a new project and running it offline is not a problem. I just tried it by turning off my wifi/network and it worked fine for me.

[image]

but if you have existing project it wont work because every time it has to check for gradle build.

Comment: I am sure the initial questions was about the computer doesn't have internet at all, like using it in an airplane, not the app doesn't have internet.